# patchify - `window_shape` is too large - smaller batch size?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a keras generator which creates patches.

The data has different size.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from patchify import patchify

class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, lr_data, hr_data, batch_size, patch_size):
        self.lr_data = lr_data
        self.hr_data = hr_data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.patch_size = patch_size

        self.lr_indices = np.arange(len(lr_data))
        self.hr_indices = np.arange(len(hr_data))
        self.min_length = min(len(self.lr_data), len(self.hr_data))

    def __len__(self):
        return  int(np.ceil(self.min_length / self.batch_size))

    def __create_patches(self, img_batch):
        
        patches = patchify(img_batch, (self.patch_size, self.patch_size, img_batch.shape[-1]), step=self.patch_size//2)
        patches = patches.reshape(-1, self.patch_size,, self.patch_size,, img_batch.shape[-1])
        
        return patches
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        start_lr = index * self.batch_size
        end_lr = min((index + 1) * self.batch_size, self.min_length)
        lr_indices = self.lr_indices[start_lr:end_lr]
        
        start_hr = index * self.batch_size
        end_hr = min((index + 1) * self.batch_size,  self.min_length)
        hr_indices = self.hr_indices[start_hr:end_hr]
        

        batch_hr = np.asarray([self.hr_data[k] for k in hr_indices])
        batch_lr = np.asarray([self.lr_data[k] for k in lr_indices])
        
        x1 = self.__create_patches(batch_hr)
        x2 = self.__create_patches(batch_lr)
       
        return [x1, x2]


LR = np.random.rand(512, 512, 9)
HR = np.random.rand(128, 128, 172)

train_gen = DataGenerator(LR, HR, batch_size=16, patch_size=32)

for lr, hr in train_gen:
    print(lr.shape)
```

I am receiving:

```
 `window_shape` is too large
```

when I try to use `patchify`.

If I use: `train_gen = DataGenerator(LR, HR, batch_size=32, patch_size=32)`,

so the same number of patches and batch_size, it runs fine.

Is there a workaround to make it work for smaller batch sizes?